# Overview of open dates in SQL database

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a database structured as follows:

```
ID    Job ID    Person    Date    Begin    End
```

It records how much time is spent on certain jobs by different people in order to calculate the total time spent on each job.

What I want to do is create a list of all time slots that have not been entered into the table. Or, alternatively, a list of all dates where the total time does not add up to a certain fixed time (let's say 8 hours). All grouped by person, as there are multiple people.

Unfortunately I have no clue as how to get started. Anyone any ideas to get me going?

EDIT:

Sample data:

```
ID    Job ID    Person    Date          Begin    End
1     0001      Bob       26/09/2016    08:00    09:00
2     0002      Bob       26/09/2016    09:00    11:00
3     0001      Bob       26/09/2016    11:00    16:00
4     0002      John      26/09/2016    08:00    14:00
5     0003      John      26/09/2016    14:00    14:30
6     0004      John      26/09/2016    14:30    15:00
```

What I'm looking for is a query that will give me:

```
Person    Date          Begin    End
John      26/09/2016    15:00    16:00
```

Or, if not possible:

```
Person    Date          Missing time
John      26/09/2016    01:00
```

For each day starting on a given day.

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (Many of them are far from ANSI SQL compliant when it comes to date/time.) Add sample table data, and the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

The last option could be as simple as:

```
Select 
    Person, [Date], CDate(#08:00# - Sum([End] - [Begin])) As MissingHours
From 
    JobTable
Group By 
    Person, [Date]
Having 
    CDate(#08:00# - Sum([End] - [Begin])) > #00:00#
```

Comment: What about days with no input at all? They won't show up in this query will they?

Comment: No. For that, create a query returning the total list, and use this in a new query with outer joins to the query above.

Answer (score 0):

> What I want to do is create a list of all time slots that have not been entered into the table

Create a table of all possible time slots (a.k.a. a calendar table) then do an 'anti-join' to this table e.g.

```
SELECT *
  FROM CalendarTable c
 WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * 
                      FROM MyTable m
                     WHERE c.date BETWEEN m.start_date AND m.end_date );
```